# how to define binary column in pas.plugin.sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, plone

I'm defining my custom model for pas.plugin.sqlalchemy.

Existing table of login details have binary field as password column. how should be define in model as binary. I tried to import _Binary class from SQLAlchemy after Googling but it doesn't import. Firstly I tried LargeBinary but when table been created its takes field type as Image which I dont want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

WEBBYFOX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not surprised that _Binary doesn't work - even if it did, it's generally a very bad idea to use something that's intended as a private class.  But "sqlalchemy.Binary" is a perfectly acceptable type.

That said, I doubt anybody's tested  pas.plugins.sqlalchemy with Binary data for the password: PAS is a way to drop-in replacements for the existing Plone system, and out-of-the-box, Plone expects passwords to be strings.